# Finding Minimum Value in Array and its index using CUDA __shfl_down function

Tags: cuda, gpgpu

I am writing a function which will find the minimum value and the index at which value was found a  1D array using CUDA.

I started by modifying the reduction code for finding sum of values in 1d array. The code work fine for sum function but I am not able to get it work for finding minimum. I am attaching the code in the message if there is any cuda guru please point out the mistake I am doing.

Actual function is below and in the test example array size is 1024. So, I am using shuffle reduction part. Problem is the out put values in g_oIdxs (gives the index) per block, and g_odata (gives the minimum value) per block is wrong compared to plain sequential CPU code.

Also values in g_odata is all zero (0) when I print it in host.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#if __DEVICE_EMULATION__
#define DEBUG_SYNC __syncthreads();
#else
#define DEBUG_SYNC
#endif

#ifndef MIN
#define MIN(x,y) ((x < y) ? x : y)
#endif

#ifndef MIN_IDX
#define MIN_IDX(x,y, idx_x, idx_y) ((x < y) ? idx_x : idx_y)
#endif

#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ < 200)
#define int_mult(x,y)   __mul24(x,y)
#else
#define int_mult(x,y)   x*y
#endif

#define inf 0x7f800000

bool isPow2(unsigned int x)
{
    return ((x&(x-1))==0);
}

unsigned int nextPow2(unsigned int x)
{
    --x;
    x |= x >> 1;
    x |= x >> 2;
    x |= x >> 4;
    x |= x >> 8;
    x |= x >> 16;
    return ++x;
}

// Utility class used to avoid linker errors with extern
// unsized shared memory arrays with templated type
template<class T>
struct SharedMemory {
    __device__ inline operator T *() {
        extern __shared__ int __smem[];
        return (T *) __smem;
    }

    __device__ inline operator const T *() const {
        extern __shared__ int __smem[];
        return (T *) __smem;
    }
};

// specialize for double to avoid unaligned memory
// access compile errors
template<>
struct SharedMemory<double> {
    __device__ inline operator double *() {
        extern __shared__ double __smem_d[];
        return (double *) __smem_d;
    }

    __device__ inline operator const double *() const {
        extern __shared__ double __smem_d[];
        return (double *) __smem_d;
    }
};

/*
 This version adds multiple elements per thread sequentially.  This reduces the overall
 cost of the algorithm while keeping the work complexity O(n) and the step complexity O(log n).
 (Brent's Theorem optimization)

 Note, this kernel needs a minimum of 64*sizeof(T) bytes of shared memory.
 In other words if blockSize <= 32, allocate 64*sizeof(T) bytes.
 If blockSize > 32, allocate blockSize*sizeof(T) bytes.
 */
template<class T, unsigned int blockSize, bool nIsPow2>
__global__ void reduce6(T *g_idata, T *g_odata, unsigned int n) {
    T *sdata = SharedMemory<T>();

    // perform first level of reduction,
    // reading from global memory, writing to shared memory
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockSize * 2 + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int gridSize = blockSize * 2 * gridDim.x;

    T mySum = 0;

    // we reduce multiple elements per thread.  The number is determined by the
    // number of active thread blocks (via gridDim).  More blocks will result
    // in a larger gridSize and therefore fewer elements per thread
    while (i < n) {
        mySum += g_idata[i];

        // ensure we don't read out of bounds -- this is optimized away for powerOf2 sized arrays
        if (nIsPow2 || i + blockSize < n)
            mySum += g_idata[i + blockSize];

        i += gridSize;
    }

    // each thread puts its local sum into shared memory
    sdata[tid] = mySum;
    __syncthreads();

    // do reduction in shared mem
    if ((blockSize >= 512) && (tid < 256)) {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 256];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 256) && (tid < 128)) {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 128];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 128) && (tid < 64)) {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 64];
    }

    __syncthreads();

#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 300 )
    if (tid < 32) {
        // Fetch final intermediate sum from 2nd warp
        if (blockSize >= 64)
            mySum += sdata[tid + 32];
        // Reduce final warp using shuffle
        for (int offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2) {
            mySum += __shfl_down(mySum, offset);
        }
    }
#else
    // fully unroll reduction within a single warp
    if ((blockSize >= 64) && (tid < 32))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 32];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 32) && (tid < 16))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 16];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 16) && (tid < 8))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 8];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 8) && (tid < 4))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 4];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 4) && (tid < 2))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 2];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 2) && ( tid < 1))
    {
        sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 1];
    }

    __syncthreads();
#endif

    // write result for this block to global mem
    if (tid == 0)
        g_odata[blockIdx.x] = mySum;
}


/*
 This version adds multiple elements per thread sequentially.  This reduces the overall
 cost of the algorithm while keeping the work complexity O(n) and the step complexity O(log n).
 (Brent's Theorem optimization)

 Note, this kernel needs a minimum of 64*sizeof(T) bytes of shared memory.
 In other words if blockSize <= 32, allocate 64*sizeof(T) bytes.
 If blockSize > 32, allocate blockSize*sizeof(T) bytes.
 */
template<class T, unsigned int blockSize, bool nIsPow2>
__global__ void reduceMin6(T *g_idata, int *g_idxs, T *g_odata, int *g_oIdxs, unsigned int n) {
    T *sdata = SharedMemory<T>();

    int *sdataIdx = SharedMemory<int>();

    // perform first level of reduction,
    // reading from global memory, writing to shared memory
    unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockSize * 2 + threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int gridSize = blockSize * 2 * gridDim.x;


    T myMin = 99999;
    int myMinIdx = -1;
    // we reduce multiple elements per thread.  The number is determined by the
    // number of active thread blocks (via gridDim).  More blocks will result
    // in a larger gridSize and therefore fewer elements per thread
    while (i < n) {
        myMinIdx  = MIN_IDX(g_idata[i], myMin, g_idxs[i], myMinIdx);
        myMin = MIN(g_idata[i], myMin);

        // ensure we don't read out of bounds -- this is optimized away for powerOf2 sized arrays
        if (nIsPow2 || i + blockSize < n){
            //myMin += g_idata[i + blockSize];
            myMinIdx  = MIN_IDX(g_idata[i + blockSize], myMin, g_idxs[i + blockSize], myMinIdx);
            myMin = MIN(g_idata[i + blockSize], myMin);
        }

        i += gridSize;
    }

    // each thread puts its local sum into shared memory
    sdata[tid] = myMin;
    sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx;
    __syncthreads();

    // do reduction in shared mem
    if ((blockSize >= 512) && (tid < 256)) {
        //sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + sdata[tid + 256];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 256], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 256], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 256], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 256) && (tid < 128)) {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 128];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 128], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 128], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 128], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 128) && (tid < 64)) {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 64];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 64], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 64], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 64], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

#if (__CUDA_ARCH__ >= 300 )
    if (tid < 32) {
        // Fetch final intermediate sum from 2nd warp
        if (blockSize >= 64){
        //myMin += sdata[tid + 32];
            myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 32], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 32], myMinIdx);
            myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 32], myMin);
        }
        // Reduce final warp using shuffle
        for (int offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2) {
            //myMin += __shfl_down(myMin, offset);
            int tempMyMinIdx = __shfl_down(myMinIdx, offset);
            float tempMyMin = __shfl_down(myMin, offset);

            myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(tempMyMin, myMin, tempMyMinIdx , myMinIdx);
            myMin = MIN(tempMyMin, myMin);
        }

    }
#else
    // fully unroll reduction within a single warp
    if ((blockSize >= 64) && (tid < 32))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 32];
        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 32], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 32], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 32], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 32) && (tid < 16))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 16];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 16], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 16], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 16], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 16) && (tid < 8))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 8];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 8], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 8], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 8], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 8) && (tid < 4))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 4];

        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 4], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 4], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 4], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 4) && (tid < 2))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 2];
        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 2], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 2], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 2], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();

    if ((blockSize >= 2) && ( tid < 1))
    {
        //sdata[tid] = myMin = myMin + sdata[tid + 1];
        sdataIdx[tid] = myMinIdx = MIN_IDX(sdata[tid + 1], myMin, sdataIdx[tid + 1], myMinIdx);
        sdata[tid] = myMin = MIN(sdata[tid + 1], myMin);
    }

    __syncthreads();
#endif

    __syncthreads();
    // write result for this block to global mem
    if (tid == 0){
        g_odata[blockIdx.x] = myMin;
        g_oIdxs[blockIdx.x] = myMinIdx;
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Compute the number of threads and blocks to use for the given reduction kernel
// For the kernels >= 3, we set threads / block to the minimum of maxThreads and
// n/2. For kernels < 3, we set to the minimum of maxThreads and n.  For kernel
// 6, we observe the maximum specified number of blocks, because each thread in
// that kernel can process a variable number of elements.
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
void getNumBlocksAndThreads(int whichKernel, int n, int maxBlocks,
        int maxThreads, int &blocks, int &threads) {

    //get device capability, to avoid block/grid size exceed the upper bound
    cudaDeviceProp prop;
    int device;
    cudaGetDevice(&device);
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&prop, device);

    if (whichKernel < 3) {
        threads = (n < maxThreads) ? nextPow2(n) : maxThreads;
        blocks = (n + threads - 1) / threads;
    } else {
        threads = (n < maxThreads * 2) ? nextPow2((n + 1) / 2) : maxThreads;
        blocks = (n + (threads * 2 - 1)) / (threads * 2);
    }

    if ((float) threads * blocks
            > (float) prop.maxGridSize[0] * prop.maxThreadsPerBlock) {
        printf("n is too large, please choose a smaller number!\n");
    }

    if (blocks > prop.maxGridSize[0]) {
        printf(
                "Grid size <%d> exceeds the device capability <%d>, set block size as %d (original %d)\n",
                blocks, prop.maxGridSize[0], threads * 2, threads);

        blocks /= 2;
        threads *= 2;
    }

    if (whichKernel == 6) {
        blocks = MIN(maxBlocks, blocks);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Wrapper function for kernel launch
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void reduce(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, T *d_idata,
        T *d_odata) {
    dim3 dimBlock(threads, 1, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid(blocks, 1, 1);

    // when there is only one warp per block, we need to allocate two warps
    // worth of shared memory so that we don't index shared memory out of bounds
    int smemSize =
            (threads <= 32) ? 2 * threads * sizeof(T) : threads * sizeof(T);

    if (isPow2(size)) {
        switch (threads) {
        case 512:
            reduce6<T, 512, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 256:
            reduce6<T, 256, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 128:
            reduce6<T, 128, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 64:
            reduce6<T, 64, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 32:
            reduce6<T, 32, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 16:
            reduce6<T, 16, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 8:
            reduce6<T, 8, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 4:
            reduce6<T, 4, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 2:
            reduce6<T, 2, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 1:
            reduce6<T, 1, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (threads) {
        case 512:
            reduce6<T, 512, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 256:
            reduce6<T, 256, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 128:
            reduce6<T, 128, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 64:
            reduce6<T, 64, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 32:
            reduce6<T, 32, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 16:
            reduce6<T, 16, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 8:
            reduce6<T, 8, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 4:
            reduce6<T, 4, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 2:
            reduce6<T, 2, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;

        case 1:
            reduce6<T, 1, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata,
                    d_odata, size);
            break;
        }
    }

}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Wrapper function for kernel launch
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void reduceMin(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, T *d_idata,
        T *d_odata, int *idxs, int *oIdxs) {
    dim3 dimBlock(threads, 1, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid(blocks, 1, 1);

    // when there is only one warp per block, we need to allocate two warps
    // worth of shared memory so that we don't index shared memory out of bounds
    int smemSize =
            (threads <= 32) ? 2 * threads * sizeof(T) : threads * sizeof(T);

    if (isPow2(size)) {
        switch (threads) {
        case 512:
            reduceMin6<T, 512, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 256:
            reduceMin6<T, 256, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 128:
            reduceMin6<T, 128, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 64:
            reduceMin6<T, 64, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 32:
            reduceMin6<T, 32, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 16:
            reduceMin6<T, 16, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 8:
            reduceMin6<T, 8, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 4:
            reduceMin6<T, 4, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 2:
            reduceMin6<T, 2, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 1:
            reduceMin6<T, 1, true> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;
        }
    } else {
        switch (threads) {
        case 512:
            reduceMin6<T, 512, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 256:
            reduceMin6<T, 256, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 128:
            reduceMin6<T, 128, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 64:
            reduceMin6<T, 64, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 32:
            reduceMin6<T, 32, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 16:
            reduceMin6<T, 16, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 8:
            reduceMin6<T, 8, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 4:
            reduceMin6<T, 4, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 2:
            reduceMin6<T, 2, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;

        case 1:
            reduceMin6<T, 1, false> <<<dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize>>>(d_idata, idxs,
                    d_odata, oIdxs, size);
            break;
        }
    }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Compute sum reduction on CPU
//! We use Kahan summation for an accurate sum of large arrays.
//! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm
//!
//! @param data       pointer to input data
//! @param size       number of input data elements
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
void reduceMINCPU(T *data, int size, T *min, int *idx)
{
    *min = data[0];
    int min_idx = 0;
    T c = (T)0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        T y = data[i];
        T t = MIN(*min, y);
        min_idx = MIN_IDX(*min, y, min_idx, i);
        (*min) = t;
    }

    *idx = min_idx;

    return;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//! Compute sum reduction on CPU
//! We use Kahan summation for an accurate sum of large arrays.
//! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm
//!
//! @param data       pointer to input data
//! @param size       number of input data elements
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
template<class T>
T reduceCPU(T *data, int size)
{
    T sum = data[0];
    T c = (T)0.0;

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
    {
        T y = data[i] - c;
        T t = sum + y;
        c = (t - sum) - y;
        sum = t;
    }

    return sum;
}

// Instantiate the reduction function for 3 types
template void
reduce<int>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, int *d_idata,
        int *d_odata);

template void
reduce<float>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel,
        float *d_idata, float *d_odata);

template void
reduce<double>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel,
        double *d_idata, double *d_odata);

// Instantiate the reduction function for 3 types
template void
reduceMin<int>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, int *d_idata,
        int *d_odata, int *idxs, int *oIdxs);

template void
reduceMin<float>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, float *d_idata,
        float *d_odata, int *idxs, int *oIdxs);

template void
reduceMin<double>(int size, int threads, int blocks, int whichKernel, double *d_idata,
        double *d_odata, int *idxs, int *oIdxs);

unsigned long long int my_min_max_test(int num_els) {

    // timers

    unsigned long long int start;
    unsigned long long int delta;

    int maxThreads = 256;  // number of threads per block
    int whichKernel = 6;
    int maxBlocks = 64;

    int testIterations = 100;



    float* d_in = NULL;
    float* d_out = NULL;
    int *d_idxs = NULL;
    int *d_oIdxs = NULL;

    printf("%d elements\n", num_els);
    printf("%d threads (max)\n", maxThreads);

    int numBlocks = 0;
    int numThreads = 0;
    getNumBlocksAndThreads(whichKernel, num_els, maxBlocks, maxThreads, numBlocks,
            numThreads);



    //  in[1024] = 34.0f;
    //  in[333] = 55.0f;
    //  in[23523] = -42.0f;

//  cudaMalloc((void**) &d_in, size);
//  cudaMalloc((void**) &d_out, size);
//  cudaMalloc((void**) &d_idxs, num_els * sizeof(int));

    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_in, num_els * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_idxs, num_els * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_out, numBlocks * sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_oIdxs, numBlocks * sizeof(int));

    float* in = (float*) malloc(num_els * sizeof(float));
    int *idxs = (int*) malloc(num_els * sizeof(int));
    float* out = (float*) malloc(numBlocks * sizeof(float));
    int* oIdxs = (int*) malloc(numBlocks * sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < num_els; i++) {
        in[i] = (double) rand() / (double) RAND_MAX;
        idxs[i] = i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_els; i++) {

        printf("\n [%d] = %.4f", idxs[i], in[i]);
    }

    // copy data directly to device memory
    cudaMemcpy(d_in, in, num_els * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_idxs, idxs, num_els * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_out, out, numBlocks * sizeof(float),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_oIdxs, oIdxs, numBlocks * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // warm-up
//  reduce<float>(num_els, numThreads, numBlocks, whichKernel, d_in, d_out);
//
//  cudaMemcpy(out, d_out, numBlocks * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
//
//  for(int i=0; i< numBlocks; i++)
//  printf("\nFinal Result[BLK:%d]: %f", i, out[i]);

//  printf("\n Reduce CPU : %f", reduceCPU<float>(in, num_els));

    reduceMin<float>(num_els, numThreads, numBlocks, whichKernel, d_in, d_out, d_idxs, d_oIdxs);

    cudaMemcpy(out, d_out, numBlocks * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(oIdxs, d_oIdxs, numBlocks * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i< numBlocks; i++)
        printf("\n Reduce MIN GPU idx: %d  value: %f", oIdxs[i], out[i]);


    int min_idx;
    float min;
    reduceMINCPU<float>(in, num_els, &min, &min_idx);

    printf("\n\n Reduce MIN CPU idx: %d  value: %f", min_idx, min);

    cudaFree(d_in);
    cudaFree(d_out);
    cudaFree(d_idxs);

    free(in);
    free(out);

    //system("pause");

    return delta;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    printf(" GTS250 @ 70.6 GB/s - Finding min and max");
    printf("\n N \t\t [GB/s] \t [perc] \t [usec] \t test \n");

//#pragma unroll
//for(int i = 1024*1024; i <= 32*1024*1024; i=i*2)
//{
//  my_min_max_test(i);
//}

    printf("\n Non-base 2 tests! \n");
    printf("\n N \t\t [GB/s] \t [perc] \t [usec] \t test \n");

    my_min_max_test(1024);



// just some large numbers....
//my_min_max_test(14*1024*1024+38);
//my_min_max_test(14*1024*1024+55);
//my_min_max_test(18*1024*1024+1232);
//my_min_max_test(7*1024*1024+94854);

//for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
//{
//
//  float ratio = float(rand())/float(RAND_MAX);
//  ratio = ratio >= 0 ? ratio : -ratio;
//  int big_num = ratio*18*1e6;
//
//  my_min_max_test(big_num);
//}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please always post a [MCVE]; do you have to use "raw CUDA" or could you use alternative approaches as well (such as thrust)?

Comment: this code is going to be part of bigger algorithm that I am parallelizing. So, having fine grained parallelism is important. This code is there in 7.5 code samples, just changed from summation to minimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a valid way to use dynamically allocated shared memory:

```
T *sdata = SharedMemory<T>();

int *sdataIdx = SharedMemory<int>();
```

both of those pointers (`sdata` and `sdataIdx`) will end up pointing to the *same* location.  (The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#shared) discusses how to handle this correctly.)

And even though you are now wanting to use twice as much shared memory (for storage of min plus index), you have not increased the dynamic allocation size, compared to the previous sum-reduction only code:

```
int smemSize =
        (threads <= 32) ? 2 * threads * sizeof(T) : threads * sizeof(T);
```

In your case, `threads` is 256 and you are allocating enough (`threads*sizeof(T)`) for the min storage but nothing for the index storage.

We can "fix" these issues by making the following changes:

```
T *sdata = SharedMemory<T>();

int *sdataIdx = (int *)(sdata + blockSize);
```

and:

```
int smemSize =
        (threads <= 32) ? 2 * threads * sizeof(T) : threads * sizeof(T);
smemSize += threads*sizeof(int);
```

With those changes, your code produces expected output:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1182
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
 GTS250 @ 70.6 GB/s - Finding min and max
 N    [GB/s]   [perc]   [usec]   test

 Non-base 2 tests!

 N    [GB/s]   [perc]   [usec]   test
1024 elements
256 threads (max)

 Reduce MIN GPU idx: 484  value: 0.001125
 Reduce MIN GPU idx: 972  value: 0.002828

 Reduce MIN CPU idx: 484  value: 0.001125
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

(I commented out the loop that was printing out all 1024 initial values)

Comment: Thank you! so much..when I read your response was at a stage in debugging where I realized somewhere is after reading from global memory and assigning value to shared memory. But would have took longer to solve actual mistake..