# CUDA Reduction minimum value and index

Tags: cuda, nvidia, reduction

I implemented a minimum reduce using `CUDA 8` by following [this](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/faster-parallel-reductions-kepler/) great explanation and modifying it

```
__inline__ __device__ int warpReduceMin(int val) 
{
    for (int offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2)
    {
        int tmpVal = __shfl_down(val, offset);
        if (tmpVal < val)
        {
            val = tmpVal;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

__inline__ __device__ int blockReduceMin(int val) 
{

    static __shared__ int shared[32]; // Shared mem for 32 partial mins
    int lane = threadIdx.x % warpSize;
    int wid = threadIdx.x / warpSize;

    val = warpReduceMin(val);     // Each warp performs partial reduction

    if (lane == 0)
    {
        shared[wid] = val; // Write reduced value to shared memory
    }

    __syncthreads();              // Wait for all partial reductions

    //read from shared memory only if that warp existed
    val = (threadIdx.x < blockDim.x / warpSize) ? shared[lane] : INT_MAX;

    if (wid == 0)
    {
        val = warpReduceMin(val); //Final reduce within first warp
    }

    return val;
}

__global__ void deviceReduceBlockAtomicKernel(int *in, int* out, int N) {
    int minVal = INT_MAX;
    for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        i < N;
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) 
    {
        minVal = min(minVal, in[i]);
    }
    minVal = blockReduceMin(minVal);
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        atomicMin(out, minVal);
    }
}
```

and it works great and I'm getting the minimum value. However, I don't care about the minimum value, only about its index in the original input array.

I tried modifying my code a bit

```
__inline__ __device__ int warpReduceMin(int val, int* idx) // Adding output idx
{
    for (int offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2)
    {
        int tmpVal = __shfl_down(val, offset);
        if (tmpVal < val)
        {
            *idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x + offset; // I guess I'm missing something here
            val = tmpVal;
        }
    }
    return val;
}

...
blockReduceMin stayed the same only adding idx to function calls
...

__global__ void deviceReduceBlockAtomicKernel(int *in, int* out, int N) {
    int minVal = INT_MAX;
    int minIdx = 0; // Added this
    for (int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
        i < N;
        i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) 
    {
        if (in[i] < minVal)
        {
            minVal = in[i];
            minIdx = i; // Added this
        }
    }
    minVal = blockReduceMin(minVal, &minIdx);
    if (threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        int old = atomicMin(out, minVal);
        if (old != minVal) // value was updated
        {
            atomicExch(out + 1, minIdx);
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work. I feel that I'm missing something important and that this is not the way to go about it, but my search turned up no results.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38176136/finding-minimum-value-in-array-and-its-index-using-cuda-shfl-down-function) may be of interest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several problems here. You need to modify both the warp and block minimum functions to propagate both the minimum value and its index every time a new local minimum is found. Perhaps something like this:

```
__inline__ __device__ void warpReduceMin(int& val, int& idx)
{
    for (int offset = warpSize / 2; offset > 0; offset /= 2) {
        int tmpVal = __shfl_down(val, offset);
        int tmpIdx = __shfl_down(idx, offset);
        if (tmpVal < val) {
            val = tmpVal;
            idx = tmpIdx;
        }
    }
}

__inline__ __device__  void blockReduceMin(int& val, int& idx) 
{

    static __shared__ int values[32], indices[32]; // Shared mem for 32 partial mins
    int lane = threadIdx.x % warpSize;
    int wid = threadIdx.x / warpSize;

    warpReduceMin(val, idx);     // Each warp performs partial reduction

    if (lane == 0) {
        values[wid] = val; // Write reduced value to shared memory
        indices[wid] = idx; // Write reduced value to shared memory
    }

    __syncthreads();              // Wait for all partial reductions

    //read from shared memory only if that warp existed
    if (threadIdx.x < blockDim.x / warpSize) {
        val = values[lane];
        idx = indices[lane];
    } else {
        val = INT_MAX;
        idx = 0;
    }

    if (wid == 0) {
         warpReduceMin(val, idx); //Final reduce within first warp
    }
}
```

[note: written in browser, never compiled or tested, use at own risk]

That should leave every block holding it's correct local minimum and index. Then you have a second problem. This:

```
int old = atomicMin(out, minVal);
if (old != minVal) // value was updated
{
    atomicExch(out + 1, minIdx);
}
```

is broken. There is no guarantee that the minimum value and its index will be correctly set in this code. This is because there is no guarantee that both atomic operations have any synchronisation and there is a potential race where one block may correctly overwrite the minimum value of another block, but then have its index overwritten by the block it replaced. The only solution here would be some sort of mutex, or run a second reduction kernel on the results of each block.

Answer (score 0):

In Ampere and newer `#if __CUDA_ARCH__ > 800` you can do this in a few lines:

For a single warp:

```
constexpr auto Everyone = -1u;
const auto minval = __reduce_min_sync(Everyone, value);
const auto minmask = __ballot_sync(Everyone, value == minval);
const auto minpos = __ffs(minmask) -1;
```

You can then store your minimums and min_positions in an array and
extract the warp that hold the minimum value and its position.

```
__shared__ float mins[32];
__shared__ unsigned min_pos[32];
const auto WarpId = threadIdx.x / 32;
mins[WarpId] = minval;
min_pos[WarpId] = minpos;
__syncthreads();
const auto WarpCount = blockDim.x / 32;
const auto ActiveMask = __ballot_sync(Everyone, threadIdx.x < WarpCount);
//Never use __activemask(), that does not work beyond Pascal.
if (threadIdx.x < WarpCount) { //This will all be in warp 0.
    const auto val2 = mins[threadIdx.x];
    const auto minpos2 = min_pos[threadIdx.x];
    //another reduction
    const auto minval = __reduce_min_sync(ActiveMask, val2);
    const auto minmask = __ballot_sync(ActiveMask, val2 == minval);
    const auto minwarp = __ffs(minmask) -1;
    printf("Minval: %f, MinThread: %i", minval, minwarp*32 + minpos);
}
```

No more loops. Note that as cool as the build-in `__reduce_xxx_sync` methods are, they are very slow if the masks are not all the same across the participating threads. The following code runs 32x slower than you'd expect.

```
const auto LaneId = threadIdx.x % 32;
const auto JustMe = 1 << LaneId;
//I know this is a no-op.
const auto example = __reduce_or_sync(JustMe, value); //execution is serialized
```